# Excel VBA - Reference chart data point by name instead of index number

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

I have a basic Gantt chart with a table as its data source, however, when another name is selected somewhere on the sheet, this table gets emptied and refilled with the data that belongs to the chosen name.

There is one data point the same for every name and I want its bar to have another color.

I know about this way to reference a data point:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Points(3)
```

But that wont work in my example because the amount of data points keeps changing and the same thing is not always in the third position.

I tried this, but like I thought it throws me a type mismatch error:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Points("SomeString")
```

Is it possible to reference a data point by its name in VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With is a simple Gantt chart that looks like this:

[image]

You can change the color of point B by first returning the XValue, match against the name your looking for and then set the corresponding point color:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangePointBColor()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim varValues As Variant
    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart

    With cht.SeriesCollection(2) 
        varValues = .XValues

        For x = LBound(varValues) To UBound(varValues)
            If varValues(x) = "B" Then
                .Points(x).Interior.Color = RGB(140, 125, 230)
            End If
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I use option explicit, should i define the varValues array as variant or string? I guess string, but just to make sure

Comment: hehe thanks ;) btw, since varValues is an array it should be `Dim varValues() As Variant` right? or am I missing something?

Comment: It worked almost perfect ;) when I selected a name that had it in first position for example, the next name I selected also got the first bar in the new color. But i fixed that by recoloring to the original color before the loop ;)

Comment: Glad it worked well for your scenario.  I believe () is implied for Variants, Option Explicit didn't throw an error for me but I'm not completely sure on how that is inferred.

Comment: Ah oke I see, well learned another thing then haha ;) thank you for your help!